# C++ Exception not caught on clang 17.0.3

Tags: c++, macos, exception, clang, c++20

This is a simplified version of a bug that I ran into today.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void run() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
}

int main() {
    try {
        run();
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and ran this code with Homebrew clang version 17.0.3 on an M1 Mac:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp
```

The exception is not caught and the program exits with:

```
Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)
```

If I remove `std::vector<int> v;` from the run function or compile it on Linux, then it works.

Edit:
So, I was originally compiling through CLion using cmake which also added `-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib`.

I tested it compiling manually, results:

```
# works
clang++ -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp

# crashes with c++11, c++17 and c++20
clang++ -std=c++20 -O0 -o main -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib main.cpp

# works
clang++ -std=c++20 -O1 -o main -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib main.cpp
```

Generated assembly files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13UKnC0mp6_3l_QULO62ts_UQHK1ZR23u?usp=share_link

My guess is that -O1 simply stripped away creating the vector, because adding more code to make sure it's kept causes a trap.

Creating an empty class inside `run()`, that has a destructor that prints something also causes this same problem.

Comment: What compiler flags do you use? Did you try a few different flags like `-std=xxx` where xxx is c++11, c++14, c++17, c++20 etc. and or different optimisation levels? [Edit] the question and put all details into the question.

Comment: Just -std=c++20.

Comment: If you add an `catch (...)` does that block catch the exception?

Comment: @NathanOliver No it does not, and code execution doesn't seem to get that far. My debugger breaks on an exception on the closing curly brace of run.

Comment: Could you please share the assembly generated by your compiler? This looks like a compiler bug (to shed any doubt you might have). If the behaviour is unchanged with `-O2`, please provide both assemblies.

Comment: @Balázsg  Did you try a few different flags like `-std=c++-17` etc.? And different optimisation levels like `-O0`, `-O1`,  `-O2`,  `-O2` ? Please [edit] and put all information into the question.

Comment: Astonishing that the `-O1` version works but the  `-O0` one doesn't. Could you post the generated assembly code for a version that works and a version that doesn't as requested before? But anyway this looks more like a problem with the `-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a misconfiguration error.

Excerpt from `brew info llvm`.

```
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

Using `-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++` the code runs as expected.

Comment: I am getting this same issue when I try compiling with llvm and exception handling. I also checked brew info llvm, and following the instructions (and in line with your instructions here) does not seem to solve the problem for me... Using -O1 also makes the code run correctly.

Comment: @Sebastian Are you sure that the compiler does not remove the code causing the problem with -O1? That seemed to be the case during my testing.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I believe that using -O1 did indeed make the code run correctly, but was not an acceptable solution for me. I switched from the updated version of clang / LLVM back to the version that Apple ships with XCode and dropped the small amount of C++20 features that I was using that were no longer supported, and all was well at that point.